# Docker (compose) and socket io - how to link containers

Tags: node.js, docker, socket.io, docker-compose

I am currently working on a project where I remake an existing project to be used in docker containers.
I have 3 different containers:

- a nodejs server that opens a socket.io connection on port 3001 and serves a webpage (that also connects to that socket.io server) on port 3000
- a MySQL database that is needed for the nodejs backend
- a small application that sends data via socket.io to the server

Now I am trying to link these containers but I am not sure if I understood the docker network just right. Am I right in assuming that in a docker-compose.yml file:

- ports: exposes ports to the host computer (and also to all other/all linked containers?)
- links: sets the start order and allows one container to user anothers exposed ports, hostname = containername
- expose: exposes ports to all linked containers only (not the host, not unlinked containers)

So I have to always link and expose? Does this always work in both directions (socket.io messages can be send back too)?

So would something like this be right (version 3 format):

```
nodeserver:
    ports:
        -3000:3000
    expose: 
        -3001
    links:
        -database
    ...

database:
    (image mysql...)

application:
    links:
        -nodeserver
     ...
```

Could the application and the webpage now both reach the socket.io server as nodeserver:3000 ?

I tried some of this already but haven't gotten it fully work so I wanted to make sure to understand everything first. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your deploy architecture, the `application` need access `nodeserver` via socket.io on port 3001, so you add a **link** with nodeserver to application, it's correct.

But the `nodeserver` serve a webpage that also connects to socket.io on port 3001, so the browser cannot connects nodeserver on port 3001.

So you just need to change `nodeserver` as below:

```
nodeserver:
ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    - "3001:3001"
links:
    -database
...
```

links:

> Link to containers in another service. Either specify both the service name and a link alias (SERVICE:ALIAS), or just the service name.
>
> Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

ports:

> Expose ports. Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port (a random host port will be chosen).

expose:

> Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be specified.

See more details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file

Comment: Thank you! The ports instead of the expose is needed here because the webpage runs on the actual host, right? If it were running in the container only expose would have worked!?
And in general "links" can only be used together with ports or expose, did I get that right?

Comment: @CodeO There are no limits for how `links` to use, `links` just add a alias of target service to the container. You can see the `hosts` file with command: `docker-compose exec nodeserver cat /etc/hosts`. I've updated my post for `ports` and `expose`.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted this answer (although I have read the docu myselft ;) ). Ok you can use `links` anytime which might help with dependencies but without a port/expose you still can't access anything from that other container, right?

Comment: Actually, it is half-right. By default, the container create by a compose open for other containers in the same network, you can test or verify with this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Shawyeok/90737876ecef7aa47b598a7854a8a674).